# Android: How to display Icon having only resource integer id?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Notification class small Icon is given as Integer resource id. How to display that in as an image in ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a `ImageView` then set the image resource for your `ImageView` by the code below

```
yourImageview.setImageResource(id); // id is your Integer resource
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I tried that before but for full working in that case we need one more thing. Image is a resource of different package.

Solution here is:

```
    Resources resources;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);

        Drawable image = resources.getDrawable(some_resource_int_id, null);
         bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the resource ID to your imageView reference object like

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
// and then set the resource id to your imageView
imageView.setImageResource(resourceID);
```